# passive motion detect

Tags: c, glut

How can I detect mouse passive motion with opengl ? In other words, how can I understand whether it is moving forward, backward, left, right ?

I have done

```
glutPassiveMotionFunc ( func ) 

void func ( int x, int y ) {

   // x and y always positive, I wait it should be negative if it goes left 
   //   acc. to  my coordinate system determined in glLookAt.
}
```

Comment: With GLUT, not with OpenGL. OpenGL is a graphics programming API and doesn't know about any input handling. GLUT is a window handling library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/glut/spec3/node51.html):

> The x and y callback parameters indicate the mouse location in window relative coordinates.

If you're interested in how the cursor moved between two frames (a delta), store the cursor position every frame and calculate the difference between the "current" position and the "last seen" position.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it with OpenGL, you do it with GLUT.

Store the previous recorded mouse position. Compare the new position with previous position, to know whether its going up, down, left or right.

Something like this:

```
int x=0, y=0;
enum { LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };
int direction;

void func(int mx, int my)
{
     if(mx < x) direction = LEFT;
     else if(mx > x) direction = RIGHT;
     else if(my > y) direction = DOWN;
     else if(my < y) direction = UP;

     x = mx;
     y = my;
}
```

The origin is at the top-left corner.

Comment: From a practical standpoint it helps to average the change, so that you get more of an average velocity.